# How to get remote file size from a shell script?

Tags: shell, filesize

Is there a way to get the size of a remote file like

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json
```

in shell script?

Comment: few examples in this page, here is one for Windows shell script (that can be double as bash script with few modification) http://superuser.com/a/1007898/429721

Comment: How about `wget --spider`?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can download the file and get its size. But we can do better.

Use [**curl**](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to get only the [**response header**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) using the `-I` option.

In the response header look for `Content-Length:` which will be followed by the size of the file in bytes.

```
$ URL="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"
$ curl -sI $URL | grep -i Content-Length
Content-Length: 134
```

To get the size use a filter to extract the numeric part from the output above:

```
$ curl -sI $URL | grep -i Content-Length | awk '{print $2}'
134
```

Comment: Used this function and wanted to send the result to a function to format the bytes to KB or MB, and it has a hidden carriage return, pipe the result to **`tr -d '\r'`** to remove them.

Comment: `curl -sI $URL | grep -i content-length`

to avoid case sensitive you have to use `-i` in grep

Comment: Not working for me `curl -sI https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js | grep -i content-length`

Comment: Use cut -d' ' -f2 instead of awk.  awk is bigger and slower than cut. And to be clear, that's a space between single quotes.  Otherwise, this answer works for me.

Comment: @Prisoner13 : LOL. Thanks for the laugh. I test cut first 7 columns in a 12mn rows `1.85 GB` file i already have that's filled with unicode, and using `=` as column delimiter. it took `bsd`-`cut` some 31.44 secs, `gnu`-`cut` 5.485s, and `mawk2` 5.437s. That's basically a tie.

Answer (score 32):

Two caveats to the other answers:

1. Some servers don't return the correct Content-Length for a HEAD request, so you might need to do the full download.
2. You'll likely get an unrealistically large response (compared to a modern browser) unless you specify gzip/deflate headers.

Also, you can do this without grep/awk or piping:

```
curl 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json' --location --silent --write-out 'size_download=%{size_download}\n' --output /dev/null
```

And the same request with compression:

```
curl 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json' --location --silent  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' --write-out 'size_download=%{size_download}\n' --output /dev/null
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with redirects. Doesn't this download the whole file also?

Comment: @TomHale I think you can just add `-L` to command to follow redirects (I don't have a handy redirecting URL to test). And, yes, it downloads the whole file.

Comment: If you can depend on the web server you're querying to return an accurate `Content-Length` for a `HEAD` request, you don't need to download the whole file. Just add `-I` to the example above to see how it returns zero (at least it does on 2-25-2019). My solution is more generalized.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to [codaddict's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497759/how-to-get-remote-file-size-from-a-shell-script/4497786#4497786), but without the call to `grep`:

```
curl -sI http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json | awk '/Content-Length/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: Ironically, the example URL you chose uses lower case header strings `content-length` which breaks your command. There are lots of ways to ignore case in awk, but this is the most bulletproof: `curl -sI http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json | awk '/[Cc]ontent-[Ll]ength/ { print $2 }'` ...of course grep is also nice ;)

Comment: I guess that the headers changed in the four years between my answer and this comment :)

Answer (score 6):

### I think the easiest way to do this would be to:

1. use cURL to run in silent mode `-s`,
2. pull only the headers `-I` (so as to avoid downloading the whole file)
3. then do a case insensitive grep `-i`
4. and return the second arg using awk `$2`.
5. output is returned as `bytes`

#### Examples:

```
curl -sI http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}'

//output: 52
```

or

```
curl -sI https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}'

//output: 86709
```

or

```
curl -sI http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip | grep -i content-length | awk '{print $2}'

//output: 1073741824
```

#### Show as Kilobytes/Megabytes

If you would like to show the size in Kilobytes then change the awk to:

```
awk '{print $2/1024}'
```

or Megabytes

```
awk '{print $2/1024/1024}'
```

Answer (score 5):

The preceding answers won't work when there are redirections. For example, if one wants the size of the debian iso DVD, he must use the --location option, otherwise, the reported size may be that of the `302 Moved Temporarily` answer body, not that of the real file.
Suppose you have the following url:

```
$ url=http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-8.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
```

With curl, you could obtain:

```
$ curl --head --location ${url}
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
...
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
...

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
...
Content-Length: 3994091520
...
Content-Type: application/x-iso9660-image
...
```

That's why I prefer using `HEAD`, which is an alias to the `lwp-request` command from the **libwww-perl** package (on debian). Another advantages it has is that it strips the extra **\r** characters, which eases subsequent string processing.

So to retrieve the size of the debian iso DVD, one could do for example:

```
$ size=$(HEAD ${url})
$ size=${size##*Content-Length: }
$ size=${size%%[[:space:]]*}
```

Please note that:

- this method will require launching only one process
- it will work only with bash, because of the special expansion syntax used

For other shells, you may have to resort to sed, awk, grep et al..

Comment: Nice answer. Would it be possible to do it in a one-liner?

Comment: size=$(HEAD ${url} | grep "Content-Length:" | sed 's/.*: //')

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to edit my previous comment which I posted too quickly.
The one-liner solution I just posted will work but at the expense of creating 2 extra processes.
In the other hand, it should be compatible with more shells.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution was not working for me, this is:

```
curl -s https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js | wc -c
```

Comment: @fguillen Don't you think it's better to get the data from the headers? As this will actually download the file buffer to `wc`.

Comment: @0x616f your are right, this information is also in the headers. Can you propose a solution and notice me? I will vote it up ;)

Answer (score 1):

To combine all the above for me works:

```
URL="http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-dvd/debian-9.5.0-i386-DVD-1.iso"
curl --head --silent --location "$URL" | grep -i "content-length:" | tr -d " \t" | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

This will return just the content length in bytes:

```
3767500800
```

Answer (score 1):

## This will show you a detailed info about the ongoing download

## you just need to specify an URL like below example.

```
$ curl -O -w 'We downloaded %{size_download} bytes\n' 
https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.2.tar.gz
```

## output

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 7328k  100 7328k    0     0   244k      0  0:00:29  0:00:29 --:--:--  365k
We downloaded 7504706 bytes
```

> **For automated purposes you'll just need to add the command to your
>   script file.**

Answer (score 1):

I have a shell function, based on [codaddict's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497786/2636454), which gives a remote file's size in a human-readable format thusly:

```
remote_file_size () {
  printf "%q" "$*"           |
    xargs curl -sI           |
    grep Content-Length      |
    awk '{print $2}'         |
    tr -d '\040\011\012\015' |
    gnumfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B # the `g' prefix on `numfmt' is only for systems
  # ^                             # that lack the GNU coreutils by default, i.e.,
  # |                             # non-Linux systems
  # |
  # |                             # in other words, if you're on Linux, remove this
  # |                             # letter `g'; if you're on BSD or Mac, install the GNU coreutils
} # |                                        |
  # +----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is old and have been sufficiently answered , but let expand upon exisiting answer. If you want to automate this task ( for checking file sizes of multiple files) then here's a one liner.

first write the URL of the files in a file:

`cat url_of_files.txt`

```
https://stpubdata-jwst.stsci.edu/ero/jw02734/jw02734002001/jw02734002001_04101_00001-seg002_nis_x1dints.fits
https://stpubdata-jwst.stsci.edu/ero/jw02734/jw02734002001/jw02734002001_04101_00001-seg003_nis_calints.fits
https://stpubdata-jwst.stsci.edu/ero/jw02734/jw02734002001/jw02734002001_04102_00001-seg001_nis_calints.fits
https://stpubdata-jwst.stsci.edu/ero/jw02734/jw02734002001/jw02734002001_02101_00002-seg001_nis_cal.fits
...
```

then from the command line (from the same directory as your `url_of_files.txt`):

```
eval $(sed -rn '/^https/s/(https.*$)/curl -sI \1/p' url_of_files.txt) | awk '/[Cc]ontent-[Ll]ength/{kb=$2/1024;mb=kb/1024;gb=mb/1024;print ( $2>1024 ? ( kb>1024 ? ( mb>1024 ?  gb " G" : mb " M") : kb " K" ) : $2 " B" ) }'
```

This is for checking file sizes ranging from `bytes` to `Gbs`. I use this line to check the fits data files  being made available by the JWST team.

It checks the file size and depending on its size , roughly converts it to a an appropriate number with B,K,M,G extensions denoting the size in Bytes, Kilo bytes, Mega bytes, and Giga bytes.

result:

```
...
177.188 K
177.188 K
236.429 M
177.188 K
5.95184 M
1.83608 G
1.20326 G
130.059 M
1.20326 G
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda do it like this, including auto-following `301/302` redirections :

> ```
> curl -ILs 'https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=ORTGK%3D%3D%3D&ro=fals' | 
>
> mawk 'NF*=!_<NF' \
>       OFS=   FS='^[Cc][Oo][Nn][Tt][Ee][Nn][Tt]-[Ll][Ee][Nn][Gg][Tt][Hh]: '
> ```

```
 1  41
```

It's very brute force but gets the job done - but that's whatever raw value being reported by the server, so you may have to make adjustments to it as you see fit.

You may also have to add the `-g` flag so it can auto handle switchover from vanilla `http` to `https` :

> ```
> curl -gILs 'http://apple.com' | 
>
> mawk 'NF *= !_<NF' OFS= \
>         FS='^[Cc][Oo][Nn][Tt][Ee][Nn][Tt]-[Ll][Ee][Nn][Gg][Tt][Hh]: '
> ```

```
 1  304

 2  106049 

    '(I''m *guessing* this might be the main site, 
      and first item was the redirection page ? )'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using awk `END` to ensure to grep only the last `Content-length`:

```
function curl2contentlength() {
    curl -sI -L -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' $1 | grep -i Content-Length | awk 'END{print $2}'
}
curl2contentlength $@

./curl2contentlength.sh "https://chrt.fm/track/B63133/stitcher.simplecastaudio.com/ec74d48c-cbf1-4764-923e-7d584dce50fa/episodes/a85954a3-24c3-48ed-bced-ef0607b7149a/audio/128/default.mp3?aid=rss_feed&awCollectionId=ec74d48c-cbf1-4764-923e-7d584dce50fa&awEpisodeId=a85954a3-24c3-48ed-bced-ef0607b7149a&feed=qm_9xx0g"
```

10806508

In fact without it would have been

```
0
0
10806508
```

Answer (score -1):

I use like this `([Cc]ontent-[Ll]ength:)`, because I got server give multiple Content-Length character at header response

```
curl -sI "http://someserver.com/hls/125454.ts" | grep [Cc]ontent-[Ll]ength: | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

`Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date, Server, Content-Type, Content-Length
Server: WowzaStreamingEngine/4.5.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, User-Agent, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 01:56:08 GMT
Content-Type: video/MP2T
Content-Length: 666460`

Answer (score -5):

different solution:

```
ssh userName@IP ls -s PATH | grep FILENAME | awk '{print$1}'
```

gives you the size in KB

Comment: This works only if we have an ssh account on the same server where the url content is hosted, which is quite a strong constraint.