# How to see all the file sizes in a web page without using 'content-length' header?

Tags: http, response

With using curl and grepping or awk whatever 'content-length' it is possible to see all the response size of a web page.

This is discussed here : [How to get remote file size from a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497759/how-to-get-remote-file-size-from-a-shell-script)

I just want to see sizes of all the files seperately in a web page. How can i do that?

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Also without using Inspector add-ons of Browsers..

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome console allows you to see such information. Under the `network` tab, you'll find useful infos for every file required by the current page, such as its size, its type (document/stylesheet/script), its status, its loading time, and much more.