# Collab Curl File to Drive in parts from multiple runtimes

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a very large file I'm trying to download **to google drive**. ~30 GB. I'm wondering if I can download this file in a new parts from different collabs to download this quicker, e.g Lets assume I have 2 runtimes running.

I know I can use curl to get ranges from the file e.g

```
curl -r 0-199,1000-1199 http://example.com/
```

Is it possible to.

1. Get the length of the file
2. Divide by 2 and download from 2 seperate ranges under different file names
3. Combine the 2 file parts into 1?

I'm not sure exactly how to do this using bash

Comment: You cannot achieve what you want to do using "curl".  For parallel streaming, you would need to use some kind of on-demand dedicated torrent utility.  But that would provide no benefit because the receiving computer becomes the throttle.  IF you can use "rsync" to access the remote file, that is probably the fastest, if you specify a single target file for download.  I've seen mention that it would also let you pick up where you left off if the connection breaks and you need to resume, but I don't do remote rsync so I can't help you with specifics there.

Comment: @EricMarceau My bad I've editted it for clarity. I'm trying to download it to google drive from Collab.   Curl supports the Range Header assuming the server you're downloading from accepts it.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497759/how-to-get-remote-file-size-from-a-shell-script)**, the following should give you the target URL's size:

```
curl -sI $URL | grep -i Content-Length | awk '{print $2}'
```

But you need to read that whole set of Answers to get the full picture of what you are dealing with.